# freezing gui while socket

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface

i am building a small gui apllication that allowd the user to
download file from the server. it got a use in socket and tkinter mostly.
but when i download a file (a movie for example) its take a time, lets say 5 minuites for example. and in that time i want a progress bar that will tart looping till the file fully downloaded. but when the client getting the file data line by line using `sock.recv`,
the all gui program is freezing!
so because of that the progress bar cannot move,
and i cannot push any buttons.
so my question is - how can i fix it? mean that the gui application wont be stack while getting data from the server, and then i can make the progress bar work.
thanks lot you guys.

Comment: you have to use a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I tried to describe (mostly pseudo-code) how you can implement a non-blocking download function with progress bar.

Hope it helps.

```
def update_progress(percentage):
    # update your progress bar in GUI

def download(callback):
    # implement your download function
    # check the full size of the file to be downloaded.
    # try to download a reasonable amount at once
    # call callback with percentage that you have downloaded to update GUI

    total = 1000000 # get total size of the file to be downloaded.
    current = 0
    block_size = 1000 # i.e., 1 KB

    while True:
        # do required operations to download data of block_size amount
        # example: sock.recv(block_size)
        current += block_size

        # calculate downloaded percentage
        percentage = (block_size * 100) / total # you may add precision if you prefer

        # call the callback function to update GUI based on the downloaded percentage
        callback(percentage)

        # check if download completed
        if current >= total:
            break

def start_download(): # bind this function to your button's click on GUI.
    # import threading

    # create a thread to execute download
    # see how 'update_progress' is passed as an argument
    thread = threading.Thread(target=download, args=[update_progress])
    thread.start()

    # execution will not be blocked here as the thread runs in the background.
    # so, any code here will run without waiting for download to be completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks you guys for the help and especially to you ohannes, i used in background
thread class, this is the code: (you need change the 'root' to the name of your tkinter window)

```
class ThreadedClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, fcn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.fcn = fcn
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.queue.put(self.fcn())

def spawnthread(fcn):
    thread = ThreadedClient(queue, fcn)
    thread.start()
    periodiccall(thread)

def periodiccall(thread):
    if(thread.is_alive()):
        root.After(100, lambda: periodiccall(thread))
        #END
```